# Do most GLM predictors' effects depend on other covariates' values because of non-linear link function, error distribution, or both?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

For many generalized linear models (GLMs), the effect of changing a predictor $x_m \in X$ on the predicted mean outcome $E[\hat{y}|X]$ depends on the values of other predictors in the model $x_{n \neq m} \in X$. This is true even when we assume additivity of the linear predictor. My understanding is that this is because the GLM link functions are non-linear transformations of the model's parameters. For example, the probit function changes more rapidly at the extreme of its domain so that $Probit'(0.1)$ > $Probit'(0.5)$, making the effect of a given *change* in the linear predictor dependent on the *value* of the linear predictor.

Assuming away interactions, am I then correct in understanding that the dependence between the effect of $x_m$ and the values of $x_n$ has nothing to do with the assumed error distribution? It would then follow that, for a GLM with an identity link function and a Poisson error distribution, the effect of $x_m$ is independent of $x_n$ -- and we might call it a linear model in contrast with the typical Poisson model assuming a log link.

Comment: I _think_ the answer is "usually but not always". For your identity Poisson vs identity Gaussian, certainly. For GLMs modelling distributions in which the expectation depends on more than one parameter (e.g. zero altered Poisson), the effect of say an $x_m$ which is regressing on $\lambda$ will also affect the mean, depending on an $x_n$ which is regressing on $p$. Which in my mind does depend on your error distribution. Hopefully I've understood what you're asking...

Comment: @AlexJ This sounds right but also wrong. I think I'm assuming the expectation is a linear transformation of the transformed linear predictor. Suppose y ~ logit(XB), you could boost the variance with y ~ logit(XB) + Z. Here Z doesn't change the dependency of the Xs on each other, but if it was logit(XB)*Z instead then it's possible...if, for example, Z is a function of X. However, then you don't have a GLM -- you have a nonlinear model. My hunch is then that since the linear predictor is the model for E[y|x] in the GLM by definition, my post is correct, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you if the GLM is the form E[y|x], which is the usual textbook definition of a GLM.